# How to design the connection between raw backend data and template with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, rest, templates

Angular novice here.

I have a REST API of my own creation that supplies data (data that has been sourced from a 3rd party and undergone very little transformation). The "heaviest" endpoint returns over 100 key-value pairs in JSON.

I also have a template that I made by hand that has places for all of this data to go. The thing is, a lot of the data my API returns must undergo light transformations before being stuck in the template.

For example:

- a string must have underscores replaced with spaces
- an ID must be resolved to both a string and an image (both retrievable from REST API) that get placed in different parts of the template.

This has to be done multiple times per page; the endpoint returns an array, with each entry containing the 100+ key-val pairs.

But **I am unsure of how to handle the transforms that need to occur between API and page display**. Should I write a controller that grabs this data from an Angular service (that in turn talks to my REST api), and then generates strings (to be placed in the template) that get placed in $scope properties? And then write a directive for each $scope element that I want to be placed in the page, and fill in my template with those directive?

It seems strange to write things this way since I'm not sure how that's different from just using curly braces to directly reference the $scope properties. Should I move more of my work into the directive code and trim down the controller, or what?

In short, I am uncertain of how to apportion the workloads and data among the tools Angular provides. I realize there are a lot of options here, but nothing I've read so far jumps out at me for how to organize this properly. If it seems like there's something I'm missing, feel free to just tell me to hit the books again, or read more on a certain subject of the framework.

Comment: you should write a service that has a getter function that gets the json data and then that service should have another method that normalizes the data by looping through each property and modifying each string.  I would seriously consider not structuring your backend json data that way though to begin with if you can avoid it.  Also if you want a more mindless approach but a more performance heavy approach you could create a filter that you apply when outputting specific strings that outputs a version of the string that does all of your replacing.

Comment: @btm1 So you think I should be doing these transforms on the backend so I have less to do on the Angular side? i.e. give Angular data that it can work with directly?

Comment: You absolutely should do this on the backend if you can. Think of angular as just another client. Should all clients have to jump through hoops to use your API?

Comment: @AndyGaskell what the above user said also AngularJS will move most of your application logic to the front end leaving the backend to do little more than serve data to AngularJS. This being said you want to reduce the amount of computation necessary on the front end.